# How can I change the colors in a ggplot2 density plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

**Summary**: I want to choose the colors for a ggplot2() density distribution plot without losing the automatically generated legend.

**Details**: I have a dataframe created with the following code (I realize it is not elegant but I am only learning R):

```
cands<-scan("human.i.cands.degnums")
non<-scan("human.i.non.degnums")
df<-data.frame(grp=factor(c(rep("1. Candidates", each=length(cands)),
           rep("2. NonCands",each=length(non)))), val=c(cands,non))
```

I then plot their density distribution like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=val,color=grp)) + geom_density()
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

I would like to choose the colors the lines appear in and cannot for the life of me figure out how. I have read various other posts on the site but to no avail. The most relevant are:

- [Changing color of density plots in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363813/changing-color-of-density-plots-in-ggplot2)
- [Overlapped density plots in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199919/overlapped-density-plots-in-ggplot2)

After searching around for a while I have tried:

```
## This one gives an error
ggplot(df, aes(x=val,colour=c("red","blue"))) + geom_density() 
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:c("red", "blue")

## This one produces a single, black line
ggplot(df, aes(x=val),colour=c("red","green")) + geom_density()
```

The best I've come up with is this:

```
ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x=cands),colour="blue")  + geom_density(aes(x=non),colour="red")
```

[image]
As you can see in the image above, that last command correctly changes the colors of the lines *but* it removes the legend. I *like* ggplot2's legend system. It is nice and simple, I don't want to have to fiddle about with recreating something that ggplot is clearly capable of doing. On top of which, the syntax is very very ugly. My actual data frame consists of 7 different groups of data. I cannot believe that writing `+ geom_density(aes(x=FOO),colour="BAR")` 7 times is the most elegant way of coding this.

So, if all else fails I will accept with an answer that tells me how to get the legend back on to the 2nd plot. However, if someone can tell me how to do it properly I will be very happy.

Comment: See [here](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Colors%20(ggplot2)/) (it gets more relevant towards the bottom, but that whole site is invaluable; bookmark it).

Comment: @joran thanks but that is the site that got me so far. Does not tell me how to change the colors of the lines though.

Comment: The section entitled "Palettes: Manually-defined" doesn't help at all? The solution is almost literally the code in that section.

Comment: @Arun I stand corrected. I tried again and it worked perfectly. I could have _sworn_ I'd tried that and various permutations before but today it worked.

Comment: @Joran see my answer to Arun. I am embarrassed now... Sorry for wasting your time guys, I will happily accept it if one of you want to turn their comment into an answer. **kicking himself**

Comment: No worries, I'll leave it to one of you two to write it up and get the rep.

Comment: Argh, I know what I did, I was trying to use `scale_fill_brewer(palette="Spectral")` and its brethren when I should have used `scale_colour_manual()`. Grrrr

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
set.seed(45)
df <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, mean=2, sd=2)), grp=rep(1:2, each=100))
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x, color=factor(grp))) + geom_density() + 
                scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")

ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x, color=factor(grp))) + geom_density() + 
                scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set3")
```

gives me same plots with different sets of colors.

Answer (score 1):

Provide vector containing colours for the "values" argument to map discrete values to manually chosen visual ones:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=val,color=grp)) +
geom_density() +
scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))
```

To choose any colour you wish, enter the hex code for it instead:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=val,color=grp)) +
geom_density() +
scale_color_manual(values=c("#f5d142", "#2bd63f")) # yellow/green
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: 'Accepted' answer is not scalable because it uses palettes. See what happens when
`df <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, mean=2, sd=2)), grp=rep(1:30, each=100))`
A real problem may require more colour variables, which are properly stored as a vector.