# Change the color of a ggplot geom a posteriori (after having specified another color)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

A function from a package returns a ggplot with preset colours that I'd like to change.

For example, let's simulate that plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) +
  geom_density(fill="#2196F3")
p
```

It is a blue-filled density plot.

I'd like to change its color a posteriori.

I've tried doing:

```
p + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#4CAF50"))
p
```

But it doesn't change anything.

I've also tried:

```
p <- p + geom_density(fill="black")
p
```

But that adds a layer on top of the previous one, without changing it.

I've also attempted to dig into the ggplot object but I got lost there.

Is there any convenient way to change the properties of a geom a posteriori?

Thanks

Comment: No, nothing convenient. You can build the grob and modify it, but that's not convenient. I think it would be easy if `fill` was mapped inside `aes` and the color mapped to it via a scale.

Comment: As a reference, I leave [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363813/changing-color-of-density-plots-in-ggplot2) here for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
#this is blue
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) +
  geom_density(fill="#2196F3")

#convert to red
p$layers[[1]]$aes_params$fill <-  'red'
p
```

[image]

The fill colour is saved in `p$layers[[1]]$aes_params$fill` and can be modified this way.

Comment: I did not know this hack. One question. How can we actually see inside of the list? `p$layers[[1]]$aes_params` prints `named list()` only.

Comment: Probably try to install the newest version of `ggplot`. Quite a few bits have changed internally. For me `> p$layers[[1]]$aes_params $fill [1] "#2196F3"` it shows the list directly. I am on `ggplot2_2.2.1`

Comment: I have the same version. I learned one thing. In your case, you do not have `fill` in `aes()`. I can see the same result; I see the color. In my case, I included `fill` in `aes()` and I see `NULL` when I run `p$layers[[1]]$aes_params$fill`.

Comment: @jazzurro That makes sense :)

Comment: So my understanding is that `p$layers[[1]]$aes_params` contains information for like fill, color staying outside of `aes()`. Is that right?

Comment: That's my understanding as well.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot. I'll take a note of this. :)

Comment: If you want to change a `colour`, you must use the British spelling e.g. `p$layers[[1]]$aes_params$colour <-  'red'`. `color` will not work.

Answer (score 2):

As Roland mentioned, I would create a dummy variable for `fill` in `aes()` then change colors.

```
set.seed(111)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000),
                 dummy = "a", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, fill = dummy)) +
     geom_density(show.legend = FALSE) +
     scale_fill_manual(values = "#2196F3")
```

[image]

```
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, fill = dummy)) +
      geom_density(show.legend = FALSE) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = "#4CAF50")
```

[image]