# Overriding Colors in Ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I made the following graph in R (from: https://t-redactyl.io/blog/2016/03/creating-plots-in-r-using-ggplot2-part-9-function-plots.html)

```
library(grid)

p9 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 1)), aes(x = x)) +

    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(0.2, 0.08),
                  aes(colour = "Mean = 0.2, Standard Deviation = 0.08"), size = 1.5) +

  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(0.4, 0.1),
                  aes(colour = "Mean = 0.04, Standard Deviation = 0.01"), size = 1.5) +

    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(0.3, 0.05),
                  aes(colour = "Mean = 0.3, Standard Deviation = 0.05"), size = 1.5) +

 stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(0.7, 0.07),
                  aes(colour = "Mean = 0.7, Standard Deviation = 0.07"), size = 1.5) + 

stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(0.5, 0.06),
                  aes(colour = "Mean = 0.5, Standard Deviation = 0.06"), size = 1.5) +

    scale_x_continuous(name = "Probability",
                       breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.2),
                       limits=c(0, 1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Frequency") +
    ggtitle("Normal function curves of probabilities") +
    scale_colour_brewer(palette="Accent") +
    labs(colour = "Groups") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(size=1, colour = "black"),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#d3d3d3"),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 14, family = "Tahoma", face = "bold"),
          text=element_text(family="Tahoma"),
          axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black", size = 9),
          axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black", size = 9))

p9
```

- Is it possible to change the "yellow" color to "red"?

Normally, I would have changed the colors like this ([Changing color of density plots in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363813/changing-color-of-density-plots-in-ggplot2)):

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(2)
data <- rbind( data.frame(type="a", lr=rnorm(100)), data.frame(type="b", lr=rnorm(100,.5,1.2)))
m <- ggplot(data, aes(x=lr)) 
m <- m + geom_density(aes(fill=factor(type)), size=2, alpha=.4) 
m + scale_fill_manual( values = c("red","blue"))
```

But in the code I posted above, I do not know where exactly I can use the "scale_fill_manual" command to replace "yellow" with "red".

- Is it somehow possible to change the "yellow" to "red"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using five colors from the "Accent" palette from `RColorBrewer`. You can  find the actual colors, like this:

```
RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5,"Accent")
"#7FC97F" "#BEAED4" "#FDC086" "#FFFF99" "#386CB0"
```

Instead of using `scale_colour_brewer(palette="Accent")`, you can instead define `stat_colors` (replacing the "yellow" color with "red", and adding names using `names(stat_colors)` like this:

```
stat_colors=c("#7FC97F", "#BEAED4", "#FDC086", "red", "#386CB0")
names(stat_colors) =  c("Mean = 0.04, Standard Deviation = 0.01",
                        "Mean = 0.2, Standard Deviation = 0.08",
                        "Mean = 0.3, Standard Deviation = 0.05",
                        "Mean = 0.5, Standard Deviation = 0.06",
                        "Mean = 0.7, Standard Deviation = 0.07"
)
```

Then, in your plot use:

```
scale_color_manual(values= stat_colors)
```

[image: p9]

Full Code:

```
stat_colors=c("#7FC97F", "#BEAED4", "#FDC086", "red", "#386CB0")
names(stat_colors) =  c("Mean = 0.04, Standard Deviation = 0.01",
                        "Mean = 0.2, Standard Deviation = 0.08",
                        "Mean = 0.3, Standard Deviation = 0.05",
                        "Mean = 0.5, Standard Deviation = 0.06",
                        "Mean = 0.7, Standard Deviation = 0.07"
)

p9 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 1)), aes(x = x)) +
  
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(0.2, 0.08),
                aes(colour = "Mean = 0.2, Standard Deviation = 0.08"), size = 1.5) +
  
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(0.4, 0.1),
                aes(colour = "Mean = 0.04, Standard Deviation = 0.01"), size = 1.5) +
  
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(0.3, 0.05),
                aes(colour = "Mean = 0.3, Standard Deviation = 0.05"), size = 1.5) +
  
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(0.7, 0.07),
                aes(colour = "Mean = 0.7, Standard Deviation = 0.07"), size = 1.5) + 
  
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(0.5, 0.06),
                aes(colour = "Mean = 0.5, Standard Deviation = 0.06"), size = 1.5) +
  
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Probability",
                     breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.2),
                     limits=c(0, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Frequency") +
  scale_color_manual(values= stat_colors) +
  ggtitle("Normal function curves of probabilities") +
  #scale_colour_brewer(palette="Accent") +
  labs(colour = "Groups") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size=1, colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#d3d3d3"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, family = "Tahoma", face = "bold"),
        text=element_text(family="Tahoma"),
        axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black", size = 9),
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black", size = 9))
p9
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Can you please show me the full code as to how you would add this line? When I tried to add this new line of code, I got the following error: Error in `+.gg`:
! Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: did you forget to add `+` at the end of all the lines within your ggplot? ; full code added